# Creating and send JSON data from PHP to JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, json, pdo

In this code I am trying to search a database with two columns, retrieve 11 pairs of those based on one of the matches (companyname; this was sent from JavaScript using POST).  Then I am trying to create a JSON data.

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: application/json");
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=pl;charset=UTF-8', 'user', 'password');
if(isset($_POST['companyname']) == true && empty($_POST['companyname']) == false) {

    $searchterm = $_POST['companyname'];
    $i=0;
    $jasondata = '{';

    $query = $db->query("SELECT companyname, axiscategory FROM axispl WHERE companyname LIKE '$searchterm%' LIMIT 11");
    $c = 1;
    while (($row=$query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) !==false && $c<11) {
        $i++;
        $companyname = $row["companyname"];
        $axiscategory = $row["axiscategory"];
        $jasondata .='"combi'.$i.'":{"companyname":"'.$companyname.'","axiscategory":"'.$axiscategory.'"},';
        $n=$row['companyname'];
        $l=strlen($n);
        if($l>50){$c = $c+2;}else{$c = $c+1;}       

    }
    $jasondata = chop($jasondata, ",");
    $jasondata .= '}';
    echo $jasondata;

}   
?>
```

Comment: **WARNING!** Your code contains an [SQL injection vulnerability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) -- you are passing raw, unfiltered, unvalidated user input directly into an SQL string. You're using PDO, so why aren't you using [prepared statements with parameterized queries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement)?  See [`prepare`](http://php.net/pdo.prepare).  Hint: when using it with a `LIKE`, you need to put the percent inside the string being escaped, not inside the SQL.

Comment: The most important question is: does it work? Have you tried it? The first thing I would change is creating the JSON string yourself - just use `echo json_encode($array)` - much easier!

Comment: @Charles Thank you! Your comment has sent me on a journey of studying more of PDO.

Comment: *"Is this code correct?  If not, what should I change?"* - Never ever ask such questions here. Highly disliked. Conrecte questions, concrete answers. And search first.

Comment: @hakre Thank you.  Will take note.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What should you change? Well, I mentioned using `json_encode` earlier, and Charles quite rightly points out the security vulnerability.

I'd also work on the code formatting as well - my recommendation is to work to a sensible margin. This used to be 80 characters for historical reasons, but 100-120 is quite a good limit now - it means you can have several code viewers stacked left-to-right on your screen without the need to scroll horizontally in each one. And you can post to StackOverflow similarly without wrapping issues!

Consider this snippet of yours:

```
$query = $db->query("
    SELECT
        companyname, axiscategory
    FROM
        axispl
    WHERE
        companyname LIKE '$searchterm%'
    LIMIT 11
");
```

Also:

```
$db = new PDO(
    'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=pl;charset=UTF-8',
    'user',
    'password'
);
```

Much more readable, eh? My motto: give your code room to *breathe*.

Comment: You're welcome, good luck with your project.